# SAP ui5 ComboBox LIstItem not showing additionalText

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to some additional text with sapui5 ComboBox control.

Here is my code

```
<ComboBox>
                    <items>
                        <core:ListItem text="1" key="1" additionalText="Draft" />
                        <core:ListItem text="2" key="2" additionalText="Revision"/>
                    </items>
                </ComboBox>
```

But its not showing the additional text . Output -
[image]

What is wrong with my code? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to enable it with the [showSecondaryValues](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ComboBox.html#getShowSecondaryValues) property of the `ComboBox`.

```xml
<ComboBox showSecondaryValues="true">
  <items>
    <core:ListItem text="1" key="1" additionalText="Draft" />
    <core:ListItem text="2" key="2" additionalText="Revision"/>
  </items>
</ComboBox>
```